# php command path issue when running multiple xampp OR multiple php version in a single xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I'm running two xampps as xampp56 and xampp72 on my windows.

**The problem is** when im trying to run composer commands.
i had php's path set to `c:/xampp/php` from my previous xampp installation.

now since that directory is no more i can't run php command from anywhere. 
is there an elegant solution for this? a solution that would still enable to run composer. phar without having to use absolute path for each php implementation

Comment: Maybe [add PHP to PATH](http://www.forevolve.com/en/articles/2016/10/27/how-to-add-your-php-runtime-directory-to-your-windows-10-path-environment-variable/)?

Comment: The problem i have two PHP. One is under `c:\xampp56\php` and the other is under `c:\xampp72\php`. I don't want to have to change the env vars everytime i need a certain php version